# Clear df-bit of incoming packets

Tags: juniper-srx, fragmentation

How I can clear DF bit from incoming packets on Juniper SRX?
As example, on Cisco router it can be done by route-map on ingress interface:

```
route-map clear-df-bit permit 10 
    match ip address 111 
    set ip df 0 

access-list 111 permit tcp any any
```

If it's even possible on Juniper?

Comment: What model of SRX? Is it running JunOS?

Comment: @Cown SRX 1400 running JunOS 12.1

Comment: Check out these links:
[Juniper Documentation](https://www.juniper.net/documentation/en_US/junos/topics/reference/configuration-statement/security-edit-df-bit.html)
and [Clear IP DF-Bit without tunnel](https://forums.juniper.net/t5/Routing/Clear-IP-DF-Bit-without-tunnel/m-p/162000#M7458)

Comment: Can you give me a little bit more context, is this inside an IPSec tunnel, typical BUM traffic, what's the application?

Comment: @JordanHead I need to remove DF-bit flag from packets that comes to inside interface on SRX and then send them via IPSEC tunnel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At this moment there's no way to reset DF-bit flag from incoming packets to Juniper SRX.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to send them via an IPSEC tunnel (as you imply in your comment above) then simply:

```
set security ipsec vpn MY-VPN df-bit clear
```

Comment: No, it's different thing. `The default behavior of DF-bit, when the traffic goes to the IPSec tunnel, is to not change the DF-bit of the inner IP header and clear the DF-bit flag on the outer IP header.` [Juniper KB](https://kb.juniper.net/InfoCenter/index?page=content&id=KB25625&actp=METADATA)

Comment: right - but with the feature above, that will clear the "inner" bit.  Doesn't this solve your issue?

Comment: df-bit clear is a default setting, so it doesn't solve issue

Comment: okay, sorry - I see now - clear is for outer header, not inner.  There is(/was) command on the J-Series: clear-dont-fragment-bit that you could simply apply to logical interface units, but this doesn't appear to be available on the SRX (even branch)

Comment: I found quote about this feature: "The statement is supported only on MX Series routers and all M Series routers except the M320 router." and it's only works for GRE tunnels.